# VB.net application stops while loading an XML multiple times

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlhttprequest

**What i have:**

I need to load an XML online. The site requires a username & password.

**My Problem:**

When I load the XML everything works fine. Yet when i load it again with a different username & password, my application gets stuck at "xmlDoc.load"

When i restart the application, It works with a different username & password. So my assumption is that the XML file or its credentials aren't beeing cleared.

I also tried loading the file into a stream via Httprequests,... and clearing them up, yet i get the same problem.

*Btw: I load use the code below inside a Function, and try to reload it minutes after that with the same Function.*

```
Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()

Dim myCred As New NetworkCredential(username, password)
Dim myCache As New CredentialCache()
myCache.Add(New Uri(url), "Basic", myCred)
Dim Resolverr As XmlUrlResolver = New XmlUrlResolver()
Resolverr.Credentials = myCache
xmlDoc.XmlResolver = Resolverr


xmlDoc.Load(url)
```

If you have any idea how i could clear this file up so i can load it again, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: Does it work if you use the first username password combination, twice in a row?